# converting php switch to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, switch-statement

I would like to get some suggestions on converting this php to javascript. Can you do this in javascript with a switch?

Not sure how to handle an array in this situation with javascript. I can not use it in php and only javascript.

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])){ 
$sch = $_POST['sch'];
$inches = $_POST['inches'];

switch($sch){

        case "40":
            $inch = array("1.5"=>1.610,"2.0"=>2.063,"2.5"=>2.469);
                foreach($inch as $k =>$v){
                    if($inches == $k){
                        echo "Result =" . $v;
                    }
                }
        break;            
        case "60":
            $inch = array("2.0"=>2.063);
                foreach($inch as $k =>$v){
                    echo $v;
                }
        break;
        case "80":
            $inch = array("2.5"=>2.469);
                foreach($inch as $k =>$v){
                    echo $v;
                }
        break;



    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="inches" id="inches">
  <option value="1.5">1.500</option>
  <option value="2.0">2.000</option>
  <option value="2.5">2.500</option>
  <option value="3.0">3.000</option>
</select>
<select name="sch" id="sch">
  <option value="40">sch 40</option>
  <option value="60">sch 60</option>
  <option value="80">sch 80</option>
  <option value="100">sch 100</option>
</select>
<input name="process" type="submit" value="Submit" id="process" />
</form>
```

Comment: Never heard about converting from PHP code to Javascript code before.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct conversion from php to javascript but of course using the same algorithm on client side is possible.

I tried to rewrite the first case in javascript with jquery. [Look here!](http://jsfiddle.net/usernamedemanded/qgcU2/3/)

I am a metric guy and I couldn't understand what this code does and what sch stands for. If you're trying to do a conversion it's better to do it mathematically instead of using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sch = '',  // here assign value for sch
inches = ''; // here assign value for inches
switch (sch) {
case "40":
    inch = {
        "1.5": 1.610,
        "2.0": 2.063,
        "2.5": 2.469
    };
    $.each(inch,
    function(key, val) {
        if (inches == val) {
            console.log("Result =" + $v);
        }
    });
    break;
case "60":
    inch = {
        "2.0": 2.063
    };
    $.each(inch,
    function(key, val) {
        console.log("Result =" + $v);
    });
    break;
case "80":
    inch = {
        "2.5": 2.469
    };
    $.each(inch,
    function(key, val) {
        console.log("Result =" + $v);
    });
    break;
}
```